# Mouse does not work while Improving posts in Low Quality review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed

While improving the posts in the Low Quality Posts review queue, mouse doesn't work inside the edit box. So, navigation and selection has to be done via keyboard.

Reviews in which the issue was observed:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5050421
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5050462

[image]
Browsers: Google Chrome and Safari (latest versions).
OS: Windows 7

Comment: Possibly related: [Occasionally unable to edit posts in low quality review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216621) and [Cannot get cursor out of edit area when editing an answer in Low Quality Posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221035)

Comment: Definitely related: [Review queue edit posts mouse doesn't work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226885)

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, as none of those posts have any answers, I will update my question with more info which were requested from OPs in those posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was fixed shortly after you reported this; see my answer on [Review queue edit posts mouse doesn't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226885/review-queue-edit-posts-mouse-doesnt-work/234329#234329) on Meta Stack Exchange.